# Microsoft Graph API - "Error authenticating with resource" 400s on calendar endpoints

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Have an application that uses the Graph API to access calendar data for users using outlook.com and office365. Integration has been live for months and working properly, but recently we've started receiving 400 "Error authenticating with resource" responses when attempting to fetch the users calendars (/me/calendars). Access tokens are not expired and our app requests the correct scopes during signup (User.Read Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access). Would appreciate any help on getting this resolved.

Comment: I am able to access the calendar using Microsoft Graph. Have you tried using Graph Explorer to check the same?

Comment: Seeing the exact same error in the Graph Explorer. 400 "Error authenticating with resource" for the /me/calendars endpoint.

Comment: I have suddenly started to see this error on a project that has been woprking frin up until now. For me, it's with groups/{id}/drive that I get a 400. Works fine in dev environment, and works fine for groups/{id}/drives but not the specific drive itself. Have opened a support request with Microsoft and will post if I get any answers.

Comment: i have the same error when trying to access my photo
Error authenticating with resource,https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value

Comment: [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1955407/benjamin-jones) did you ever get an answer? I have have the same problem since yesterday on one of the tenants in my multitenant app

Comment: Any updates to this? Im still seeing this issue

Comment: Anything on this.  I'm also receiving this on most of the endpoints